# MySQL (5.5.17) unable to start after installing XAMPP (1.7.7)

Tags: mysql, xampp

MySQL (5.5.17) 64 bit was working fine until I installed XAMPP (1.7.7) which contains MySQL (5.5.16) 32 bit.

Now it (MySQL (5.5.17)) says:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

I tried everything (changing port etc) including uninstalling/installing MySQL server & XAMPP. Still no use.

Comment: If you're on Windows, have you checked if the MySQL service is running? Where do you get this message?

Comment: I am on Windows 7, When I try to start MySQL server 5.5.17, I don't want to use MySQL installed by XAMPP

Comment: In that case, can you please elaborate (by editing your question) on by what means you have MySQL installed, as well as when and where you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can run mysql server and xampp-mysql server both using different port no. By default your Mysql server (5.5.17) is running on 3306 port no. It's conflicting with xampp mysql server. So You can set it 3307 in its my.cnf and restart. Now when run mysql client then mention port no. for ex-

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword -hlocalhost --port 3307
```

Comment: Tried changing port. MySQL (5.5.16) now runs on port 3308, but MySQL(5.5.17) is still not running.

Comment: @JohnStrowsky run mysql server 5.5.17 on 3305 or another port instead of 3306. It will work